# You also need to pass object to template in views.py

Tags: python, html, django

**One user told me to pass the object to template in views.py**.

I created a model in django and wanted to show the title of the object I created using the model in my html code. 
My code for the model is:

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And my html code is:

```
<html>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Branding -->
            <a href="/"><span class="branding">Movies & Other</span></a>
            <a href="/admin"><span class="adminpanel">Admin panel</span></a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <h1 class="movietitle">{{ video.title }}</h1>
    <div class="videoDetails">
        <video width="700" height="430" controls>
            <source src="uploadvideos/videos/yt/yt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**I created a object in the Video model in the admin panel but it doesn't show the title of it.**

Here's my views.py

```
def index(request):
    movie_list = Video.objects.order_by('id')
    context = {'video_list': movie_list}
    return render(request, template_name='uploadvideos/index.html', context=context)


def movie(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Video, title=movie_id)
    context = {'movie': movie}
    # return HttpResponse(f"You're viewing {movie.title}")
    return render(request, template_name=f'uploadvideos/{movie.title}/movie.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `view.py` also.

Comment: Are you trying to display the video title which would change based on the model value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use just {{ video }} in template  if **str**() return self.title
You also need to pass object to template in views.py

Comment: How do I pass the object to the template? here's my views.py file:
```Python
def movie(request, movie_id):
    movie = get_object_or_404(Video, title=movie_id)
    context = {'movie': movie}
    # return HttpResponse(f"You're viewing {movie.title}")
    return render(request, template_name=f'uploadvideos/{movie.title}/movie.html', context=context)

```

Comment: @Lol123abc Please edit the question and paste that code there, as requested in the comments shortly after you asked the question.

Comment: Still you do not need to use movie.title. You defined __str__ to return title as a info about object

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an object called `movie`, so you should use that in the template: `{{ movie.title }}`.

However I can't quite understand what you are doing here. Your template path implies that you have separate templates for each video, which is very odd indeed; you seem to have missed the point of templates quite a bit. Templates should be generic, and all the data should come from the context. If you had a separate template for each video you might as well hard-code all the content.

Comment: that's the way I thought it should be done since you upload a video and choose a title and it creates a new folder with the title of the video and puts the movie.html there but could you tell me how I should do it? Like how I would make so when you go to **/movie/yt** that it actually shows the correct movie and title?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Isn't that what you are doing already?